# Display error messages using c# mvc with razor view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display error messages dynamically i.e, when the cursor moves out of the field but not when the form is submitted.

My requirement is like this:-
I have to design a registration form with some fields like name,address,phone number,email,password etc.
i designed it & saved the data successfully in DB but what i exactly required in the sense i have to display error messages dynamically without using **"ajax"** as i have already stated ...

My code is like this:-

View:-

```
<div class="venfor_line5" popText><label>@Resources.Resources.VendorReg_phoneNumber<img src="~/images/star.png" /> </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.MobileNumber, new { @class = "input" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNumber)</div>

    <div class="venfor_line1" popText = @Resources.Resources.VendorReg_emailHintStr>
    <label>@Resources.Resources.VendorReg_email<img src="~/images/star.png" /> </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Email, new { @class = "input" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</div>
```

I have gone through many references but not found exactly what i am looking for.Any help would be greatly appreciated. can anyone guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: `ValidationMessageFor` is used for server side validation messages. If you want client side validation you will need to implement it yourself with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's focusOut() method to perform validation. Something like:

```
$('#elementId').focusOut(function(){
    //do validation here
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response aquaraga. I already provided the validation code in model class so, I think it is not require to provide validation code again in focusout function()???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unobtrusive jQuery validation you could eagerly enable it so that it is automatically triggered onblur without requiring the user to submit the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    settngs.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such fast response Darin Dimitrov. Actually one of my colleague did this in some other form he got it. I simply followed him but not working in my form. I also tried the code posted by you, which is not working too. if you don't mine,can you post your mail id i will send you the code???